# Somewhat convoluted ssh issue. Can ping, but not ssh, but only from on-site

Tags: networking, ssh

I am trying to ssh into my server at work (CentOS) from my laptop (Ubuntu). When I am at home, I do it by running the following script on the server (I start it while I am physically at work):

```
ssh -R (port #):localhost:22 (name@home ip)
```

I do this because it doesn't accept connections from external IPs. Then, I can ssh into the specified port on my laptop, and it works fine.

However, when I am actually at work, I cant ssh to the server. The other people in my office can. They do this very simple command (only works while they are at work, since they need an IP from inside the system):

```
ssh (username)@(work ip)
```

And they are automatically logged in. When I do that, I get no response; no public key denial, no wrong username, no response at all. Eventually it times out. But I know the server has ssh running, because everyone else can do it.

Additionally, if I do this on my laptop, while at work:

```
ping (work ip)
```

I do get response packets, with no loss, almost no lag. But ssh doesn't work.

I can ssh to other places from my laptop, both while I am at home and at work. So my laptop is properly configured to ssh to things, it just doesn't reach the work server for some reason. I talked to the guy who set  it up and he insists there is no whitelist; the only security from internal IPs (and I am physically on site, so I have an internal IP, so there should be no need to do the ssh -r like I do at home) is the private/public RSA key system, and I know the keys must be already set up, because it works when I do the ssh -R from home. Plus, if the keys were not set up, I would get a public key denial, instead of no response at all, right?

If I do ssh -vv, this is the last line before it times out:

```
debug1: Connecting to ccny6 [WORK IP] port 22.
```

I see other people have posted similar questions, but the responses they seem to generally be "is the server running the ssh service" etc, which I know it is as other people can ssh to do (as can I if I'm using the ssh -r tunnel), so none of those responses did me much good, unfortunately.

Summary: I can ssh to a server from OFF site via a ssh tunnel, but can't ssh to it while I am right next to it using direct ssh, even though I can ping it, and others can ssh to it.

Comment: Have you tried connecting with another user but the same laptop? If yes, is there still the timeout issue?

Comment: Yes, still a timeout. I can also leave no username and do

    ssh (workip)

(as one person the lab does, and it automatically puts it in his user becuase of his rsa key) and there is a timeout that way too.

Comment: ...oops, I forgot to take part out, idiot me... But nobody can get in from an external IP anyway.

Comment: I was actually only interested in whether the IP was resolving correctly

Comment: It is, I put that in my hosts for a shortcut. But the same result happens if I type the ip manually.

Comment: I'd love to look at the sshd_config file on the ssh server.

Comment: telnet <ssh_server_ip> 22 # will tell if the server is even responding.  If it is, you will need to set log reporting to debug, probably on both ends, to see what's blocking the connection.  The remote ssh script is bypassing some suspects, like firewalls, IPCHAINS (or whatever), and a few other things.  A wild but educated guess would be that your work IP is not in AllowUsers or is in DenyUsers or you are other wise blacklisted or not on a needed allow list.

Comment: The telnet command just hung on "trying (IP)..." forever.
I don't have permission to read sshd_config, it seems. I'm sure I can get my boss to cat me the contents though, I will post them when I have them. He told me earlier there he never set up an allow list or whitelist or anything, and other people (both with sudo access and without) have had no trouble doing what I am trying to do.

Comment: I should add that my boss (who set up the whole system) thinks it's a problem on my end, not the server's end, although he has no idea what it could be.

Comment: If telnet to port 22 gets no response you're failing before the sshd process even gets started.  I suspect that your laptop IP is being blocked by a firewall or the ssh server is not allowing port 22 requests from your IP.  The easiest fix for you would probably be to get a new IP.  Either expire the lease and get a new one if you have a DHCP address or assign yourself a new one if it's a static IP.  If you can ssh into other machines using port 22 then it's 99% likely that the problem is NOT on your end.

Comment: Boss emailed me a copy of sshd_config, along with another claim that the problem is on my end and that he never had to give special permissions to anyone.
Here is sshd_config:
https://pastebin.com/QRTnr6ER

I don't see why my laptop's IP would be blocked and my labmates and boss's wouldn't, because they never had to get anything unblocked by IT. We are at a university with IT people who are very unhelpful, so I'm not really sure if I'll be able to get myself a new IP (the lab computers, which are wired in, have static IPs, I'm not sure if my laptop does). I guess I will try that if I can.

Comment: I was indeed able to ssh to this service:
http://sdf.org/
I made an account to test if I could log in via ssh and I could. I also tried ssh'ing into git, although it I was denied due to the public key (but that's a response, not a "no response", so I assume my ssh request was not blocked). If my laptop's IP was blocked, is that likely to stop me being able to ping the server? Because I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on our lengthy conversation it seems quite likely that this is not a Ubuntu problem.  And, in fact, the problem you describe seems to be on the server side and not anything to do with your laptop.  Therefore, my "solution" would be to ping various IPs in your subnet until you find one that does not respond.  Then, change your laptop to use that IP as a static IP.  Test to see if you can now connect to the server via ssh.  I'll bet a diet coke this will work.  Then, go back to your old IP settings and present your findings to your uncooperative IT guys, who should thank you for doing their job for them.

Comment: Small update: We figured it out: the log-on I was using to get onthe wifi  was turned into a student account by IT when it was created for some reason. This was causing the ssh request I was sending to the server to be killed. We went to IT and fought with them for a week to turn my account into a faculty account. They did and the problem was solved. We discovered this when my co-worker tried on my laptop but didn't know my wifi password so used his own; IT certainly refused to tell us this was their policy even when we asked afterwards. We never thought it would be something like this...

Comment: I love it when my answer is correct :)

Comment: Well, you were right that it wasn't a Ubuntu problem... but it wasn't really an IP problem either, lol! Still, thanks for helping me diagnose...